# Unable to filter props list in onChangeHandler function in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, react-redux, react-props

Below is the onChangeHandler function.

```
const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
console.log(props.PolicyDtoList.filter(a => a.vc_policy_code.includes(event.target.value)))
console.log(props.PolicyDtoList)
}
```

Below is the retrieval of props list.

```
props.PolicyDtoList && props.PolicyDtoList
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
            .map((record, index) => {
              return(
                
                <TableRow  key={index} className={classes.tableBodyRow}>
                    <TableCell className={classestable.tableCell} >{record.vc_policy_code }</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className={classestable.tableCell} >{record.vc_policy_name }</TableCell>
                    <TableCell className={classestable.tableActions}>
                        <Tooltip
                          id="tooltip-top"
                          title="Edit Policy"
                          placement="top"
                          classes={{ tooltip: classestask.tooltip }}
                        >
                          <IconButton
                            aria-label="Edit"
                            className={classestask.tableActionButton}
                            onClick={() => {handleEditPolicy(record)}}
                          >
                            <Edit
                              className={
                                classestask.tableActionButtonIcon + " " + classestask.edit
                              }
                            />
                          </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                           
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              )
            })
```

List shows data when I retrieve. but when I search some string for policy code onChangeHandler functions shows two different console logs. And still props list does not filter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YjB3.png)

First array shows filtered props list and other shows unfiltered, mean props list is unfiltered originally.

Comment: Where does props.PolicyDtoList come from and if they come from redux store then why not do the paging and filtering in the [selector](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)?

Comment: filter doesn't mutate the original array which is what it seems like you are expecting. You should either save the filtered result in state or perform filtering based in input in render

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some small example. How can I mutate the array and achieve this filtering.

Comment: to HMR : props.PolicyDtoList comes from api using redux store and const mapStateToProps = state => ({

  PolicyDtoList: state.policyReducer.PolicyDtoList.policyDtoList
})

Comment: Now I did it like this it changes the destructive variable. but list still same. const newArray = PolicyDtoList.filter(a => a.vc_policy_code.includes(event.target.value));
    PolicyDtoList = newArray;
    console.log(newArray)  
    console.log(PolicyDtoList)